# Show the div if get the info from SQL in the dropdown list is selected

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have problem in displaying my `div#contenedoropots` element. When I get the info from SQL it shows the dropdown list "OTROS". If "OTROS" is selected from SQL it must show the `div#contenedoropots` but i can't find the problem, i tried many times to solve of ways differents  to show.

**HTML & PHP**

```
<option id="copiado"            
                <?php 
                    if($columna['tipo_defecto'] != "" && $columna['tipo_defecto'] != "CALIDAD"
                        && $columna['tipo_defecto'] != "INOCUIDAD"
                        && $columna['tipo_defecto'] != "DAÑO POR MANEJO"
                        ){                          
                        echo 'selected ';
                        echo 'value="'.$columna['tipo_defecto'].'"';
                        if ($columna['tipo_defecto']:selected) {
                                                echo "
                                                        <script type='text/javascript'>
                                                            document.getElementById('contenedoropots').style.display = 'block';
                                                        </script> 
                                                     ";
                                            }                   
                    }
                    else if($columna['tipo_defecto'] == "" || $columna['tipo_defecto'] == "OTROS"){
                        echo 'value="OTROS"';                       
                    }                       
                ?>
            >OTROS</option>

<div id="contenedoropots" style="display:none">
                <label id="labelcopiarA" for="cpOtros">Especificar:</label>
                <input id="copiar" type="text" name="cpOtros"  onkeyup="copiarValue();" value=""/>
            </div>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
function mostrarOtros(opOts){
    if (opOts.value == "OTROS") {
        document.getElementById('contenedoropots').style.display = 'block';
    }
    else if (opOts.value != "CALIDAD" && opOts.value != "INOCUIDAD" && opOts.value != "DAÑO POR MANEJO" && opOts.value != "") {        
        document.getElementById('contenedoropots').style.display = 'block';       
    } 
    else if (opOts.value == "CALIDAD" || opOts.value == "INOCUIDAD" || opOts.value == "DAÑO POR MANEJO" || opOts.value == "") {        
        document.getElementById('contenedoropots').style.display = 'none';        
        $("#copiado").val('OTROS');
        $('#copiar').val('');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

there is no  for option and you can't give to option **id="copiado"**

```
<option id="copiado"            
                <?php 
                    if($columna['tipo_defecto'] != "" && $columna['tipo_defecto'] != "CALIDAD"
                        && $columna['tipo_defecto'] != "INOCUIDAD"
                        && $columna['tipo_defecto'] != "DAÑO POR MANEJO"
                        ){                          
                        echo 'selected ';
                        echo 'value="'.$columna['tipo_defecto'].'"';
                        if ($columna['tipo_defecto']:selected) {
                                                echo "
                                                        <script type='text/javascript'>
                                                            document.getElementById('contenedoropots').style.display = 'block';
                                                        </script> 
                                                     ";
                                            }                   
                    }
                    else if($columna['tipo_defecto'] == "" || $columna['tipo_defecto'] == "OTROS"){
                        echo 'value="OTROS"';                       
                    }                       
                ?>
            >OTROS</option>
```

replace and check this is working or not then i will tell you next step

```
 <select onchange='mostrarOtros(this.value)'>
    <option value="" >Select</option>
    <option       <?php
                            echo 'value="OTROS"';                       

                    ?>
                >OTROS</option></select>
```

Comment: Now if i want to update the info, i did the query for update the info, i clicked a ID and shows all the info and check very well but i saw the dropdown list "OTROS" is selected but the div#contenedoropots doesn't shows the value to especify because i did the condition about if the OTROS is selected it must shows the div#contenedoropots.

Comment: the selected condition apply from the javascript no it php after the submit you can set the php condition before that the your php code will do nothing if you want i put the after submit condition

Comment: if you want to add the selected condition put end of document so it can run.